# Which row limit has SQL in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'd like to know how many rows may have the data extension susceptible of being treated by a SQL.

I have 20 million records in my Data extension, so I would like to know how many rows can I assume in my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL queries in  Marketing Cloud are bound to what can be run in 30 minutes. So to answer your question, the  while the number of rows might be a factor (i.e too many rows) other factors include:

- Number of columns (labels)
- The complexity of the queries (joins , unions, computationally expensive)
- Using Primary Keys in your data extensions make your queries faster
- Making your SQL queries sargable See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)
- Querying system data views takes more time

In general, try to keep the above factors to a minimum of you have to. In your use case, I doubt you are in the position to reduce the number of columns. So I would limit the use of joins, querying data tables and make my queries sargable.